# Image flickering when moving and animaring in VB6

Tags: animation, vb6, flicker

I am using VB6 make a game. You move with the arrow keys, and also when you move there is a animation. I have cached the character that move's sprites into a stdPicture array, but still get flickering every time for some reason. How can I stop this? I am using an image object with transparent sprites and a solid background. I get flickering with white background on sprite and even in a picture box. Is there any way to stop the fickering? Currently I animate with LoadPicture() and I move with Image.Left = Image.Left +/- 200 etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Wow! Why havent I stumbled upon this yet? I just found the solution! The solution is to use Flash. Using the Shockwave flash object removes the flickering and you can have animations. Its a double win!

Comment: -1 Your answer doesn't have anything to do with VB6. @Paul Sasik posted an answer that would help you achieve your goal using VB6.

Comment: This answer helped finish the question and Paul's method never worked for me. That wasnt the problem. the problem was the pause function.

Comment: So you repaired the engine by buying a new car?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yep! VB6 is outdated and this problem just couldnt be fixed. Just like my old car.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double buffering which VB6 does not provide automatically. See [this forum question](http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=16179) for a VB6 solution (three quarters down the page.) In .NET you simply set a Form's double buffered property to true and it will draw flicker-free. Have you considered using VB.NET instead?

Here's [another forum post](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1387082) with VB6 double buffer examples.